# Term for "Rent calculation according to store revenue"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Shopping centers and malls can institute a type of charge added to a base rent price.
This charge is calculated -in most cases - based on the tenant's monthly revenue. In most cases the turnover charges will be calculated as a percentage of the store revenue.

For example, a store's monthly base rent is 8,000 dollars, but in addition there is a stipulation that the store needs to pay 10% of its revenue. If it sells $100,000 one month, it needs to pay $10,000 (and if it sells $70,000 it needs to pay the base $8,000).

What is the proper term for this stipulation, in *American* English?

Example sentence:

> The rent is $8,000, but together with this month's _________, $10,000.

Comment: Perhaps you could call it the pro-rata rent?

Comment: @IanS - No.  The term pro-rata refers to a partial payment for a partial usage, for example for starting or stopping service in the middle of a billing cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [percentage lease](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/percentage+lease) if you refer to the complete amount that is due.

> A lease that requires rent payments based on a percentage of the gross sales of the tenant. It is common with retail leases and food and beverage leases. Most contain a minimum payment clause so that if gross sales drop below a certain level the rent will be the minimum payment rather than a percentage of sales.

Comment: A percentage lease is a lease in which the rental is calculated as a percentage of turnover.  A lease which includes a "Turnover rental" clause is the most common lease in retail. The tenant pays whichever is higher between the base rental and the agreed percentage of turnover.

Comment: @DanielGee - can you back this up with a source? Do you have personal experience in the matter?

Comment: @Helmar this link suggests that a percentage lease is not always the entire rent, but can also be a supplement: https://www.propertymetrics.com/blog/2014/01/16/percentage-rent/

Comment: @DAE, no source, just personal experience. I work for a retailer which has around 450 stores.

Answer (score 1):

In the property profession it's referred to as "turnover rental." A percentage lease would be a lease in which the rental is only based on a percentage of the turnover.